# axios get with backtick and query

Tags: javascript, https, axios

i try do a https request using this axios code:

```
this.$axios.$get(`http://localhost:3000/answersExcel/${this.id}` +
                            `?date1=${this.answer[0]}` +
                            `&date2=${this.answer[1]}`
                    )
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response)
                        this.answers = response.forms.answer
                    })
```

at first it works when there is only one query for date 1, but when date 1 and date 2 is fill it returns

```
 xhr.js?b50d:187          GET http://localhost:3000/answersExcel/6361c5aaf7a02c177ebebb27?date1=2022-11-02&date2=2022-11-24 500 (Internal Server Error)
    dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js?b50d:187
    xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?b50d:13
    dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js?5270:53
    Promise.then (async)
    request @ Axios.js?0a06:88
    Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js?0a06:129
    wrap @ bind.js?1d2b:9
    axiosExtra.<computed> @ axios.js?10e8:44
    fetchData @ BtnDownloadData.vue?e9a6:86
    click @ BtnDownloadData.vue?f266:174
    invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3015
    invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1813
    invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3015
    Vue.$emit @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3714
    click @ VBtn.ts?0eff:162
    invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3015
    invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1813
    original_1._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7458
    createError.js?2d83:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
        at createError (createError.js?2d83:16:1)
        at settle (settle.js?467f:17:1)
        at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js?b50d:54:1)
```

anyone know where i did wrong here?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error mean the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. Could you check your web server?

Comment: uhm i cannot find where its wrong..